# How to get collapsed nodes in cytoscape.js

Tags: cytoscape.js

I have some nodes which are **grouped and collapsed**.
when I get nodes with `cy.nodes()`, I only get expanded nodes.

how to I can get all nodes that aren't expanded and not rendered in the current view?

Comment: How do you collapse your nodes? By using cytoscape.js-expand-collapse extension or another method?

Comment: yes, I did it by cytoscape.js-expand-collapse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it by using `api.getCollapsedChildren(node)` as written in **[cytoscape.js-expand-collapse](https://github.com/iVis-at-Bilkent/cytoscape.js-expand-collapse)** document.

```
let children = collapseApi.getCollapsedChildren(node);
if (children && children.length > 0) {
   children.each((child) => {
       let nodeId = child.id();
   });
}
```